# iOS dynamic row width

Tags: iphone, ios, width, tablerow

Is there a way I could make the text on a row occupy the whole space , depending on the mode (landscape or portrait ) without inserting a new line after each character at a certain index ?

This is how it looks on portrait mode;

[image: portrait mode]

And in landscape;

[image: landscape mode]

As you can see, in landscape mode, the text is not well formatted.

Comment: The layoutSubviews method in your custom cell is not properly implemented. Paste some code here from the section where you do the layout for you cell. Also, for you case, the label can be set to use the autoresizing mask with flexible width. (this way it will occupy the remaining space each time the cell you redraw the cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass, you need to override the `layoutSubviews` method in your subclass.

If you are adding subviews to your table cell in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, use `label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` on your text label.

If you are laying out the cell in Interface Builder, make sure you have set the autosizing anchors on the text label so that it expands when its superview expands. You will find the autosizing anchors in the fifth tab (the one with the image of a ruler) of the Utilities pane in Xcode 4.2.